# GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 41657 while running container

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I need some help here,

- After building the containers successfully
- On hitting the host, we are getting these logs
  `GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 41657 while running container`
  [image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're running out of `/pub/` do you actually HAVE a favicon.ico file there?  This wouldn't be a generated file.  Your browser is requesting it at this path, so you can either add it, or drop a symlink to a favicon in static content if needed.

Comment: Hi @douglas, thanks for your answer, but still the issue exit.
After successfully setup of Magento 2, when I try to access my host domain, it redirects me to GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 41657 while running container
---> After debugging I found that the files in pub/static are not generated, even after try bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
--->under pub/index.php, it got failed at here
```$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);```